# Show multiple lines output in Vim script?

Tags: vim

My vim script runs multiple commands (2 actually) which output message. When i type in these 2 commands in command mode, there will be 2 lines output, but when I put these 2 commands in script, the output would only for the last line. Use below 2 commands as example, I only see ` world" when put it into Vim script file. Is there a way to show both lines?

```
:echo "hello" | echo " world"
```

BTW: I can use `:echon` to get the whole content above, but it would not work if replace echo with other commands which also output to console.

Comment: I don't get the behavior you are seeing. I stuck your line in a function, I see two lines of output.

Comment: @FDinoff, I can repro it easily. I put these commands in a function with s: prefix in Vim script, not sure whether this matters.

Comment: That probably matters. Can you post the complete function you are using?

Comment: @FDinoff, make a separated repro may not be easy. Check https://github.com/ThomsonTan/Vim/blob/master/_vimrc, I would like to append multiple `echo` commands to the line 208, but I only get the last line. Trigger this line is easy, just hit space key anywhere in the opened doc.

Comment: Get rid of the `<silent>` on the mapping.

Comment: I deleted my answer. There are other problems with the function. I believe the function should handle executing the other commands instead of returning them (for an expression mapping). (The function should restore cursor position). I however don't have the time to look into that right now.

Comment: @FDinoff thanks for looking at this. I found that when cmdheight=1, there is an extra prompt which indicates to hit `Enter` to dismiss the multiple lines output. Set cmdheight may solve but far from my original intention. I am wondering is there a way to capture the output of existing command, then remove `<CR>` from the output string and re-output it.